# How to limit FPS in WP8 directX app

Tags: windows-phone-8

game seem run too quickly in some scene,
I wanna limit fps at 30.
I am using pure-cpp d3d.
I find SetWaitableTimer is not available in WP8 (which i use to limit fps in desktop)

Answer (score 0):

SleepConditionVariableCS is available in WP8 here is the code for sleep

```
struct WaitTimeData
{
    CONDITION_VARIABLE conditionVariable;
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;

    WaitTimeData()
    {
        InitializeConditionVariable(&conditionVariable);
        memset(&criticalSection , 0 , sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION));
        //InitializeCriticalSection(&_CriticalSection); wp8 has no this func
        criticalSection.DebugInfo = (PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG)-1;
        criticalSection.LockCount = -1;
    }
};

int WPSleep(unsigned int ms)
{
    static WaitTimeData s_wtd;

    SleepConditionVariableCS(
        &s_wtd.conditionVariable,
        &s_wtd.criticalSection,
        ms
        );

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_TIMEOUT)
    {
        SetLastError(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```